# TypeError: prediction() takes at least 5 arguments (5 given)

Tags: python

I am running this code:

```
def prediction(self, X_calib, Y_calib, X_valid, Y_valid, plot_components=False):

#Run PLS including a variable number of components, up to 40,  and calculate MSE
mse = []
component = np.arange(1, 40)
for i in component:
    pls = PLSRegression(n_components=i)
    # Fit
    pls.fit(X_calib, Y_calib)
    # Prediction
    Y_pred = pls.predict(X_valid)

    mse_p = mean_squared_error(Y_valid, Y_pred)
    mse.append(mse_p)

    comp = 100*(i+1)/40
    # Trick to update status on the same line
    stdout.write("\r%d%% completed" % comp)
    stdout.flush()
stdout.write("\n")

# Calculate and print the position of minimum in MSE
msemin = np.argmin(mse)
print("Suggested number of components: ", msemin+1)
stdout.write("\n")

if plot_components is True:
    with plt.style.context(('ggplot')):
        plt.plot(component, np.array(mse), '-v', color = 'blue', mfc='blue')
        plt.plot(component[msemin], np.array(mse)[msemin], 'P', ms=10, mfc='red')
        plt.xlabel('Number of PLS components')
        plt.ylabel('MSE')
        plt.title('PLS')
        plt.xlim(xmin=-1)

    plt.show()

# Run PLS with suggested number of components
pls = PLSRegression(n_components=msemin+1)
pls.fit(X_calib, Y_calib)
Y_pred = pls.predict(X_valid) 

# Calculate and print scores
score_p = r2_score(Y_valid, Y_pred)
mse_p = mean_squared_error(Y_valid, Y_pred)
sep = np.std(Y_pred[:,0]-Y_valid)
rpd = np.std(Y_valid)/sep
bias = np.mean(Y_pred[:,0]-Y_valid)

print('R2: %5.3f'  % score_p)
print('MSE: %5.3f' % mse_p)
print('SEP: %5.3f' % sep)
print('RPD: %5.3f' % rpd)
print('Bias: %5.3f' %  bias)

# Plot regression and figures of merit
rangey = max(Y_valid) - min(Y_valid)
rangex = max(Y_pred) - min(Y_pred)

z = np.polyfit(Y_valid, Y_pred, 1)
with plt.style.context(('ggplot')):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
    ax.scatter(Y_pred, Y_valid, c='red', edgecolors='k')
    ax.plot(z[1]+z[0]*Y_valid, Y_valid, c='blue', linewidth=1)
    ax.plot(Y_valid, Y_valid, color='green', linewidth=1)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
    plt.ylabel('Measured')
    plt.title('Prediction')

    # Print the scores on the plot
    plt.text(min(Y_pred)+0.05*rangex, max(Y_valid)-0.1*rangey, 'R$^{2}=$ %5.3f'  % score_p)
    plt.text(min(Y_pred)+0.05*rangex, max(Y_valid)-0.15*rangey, 'MSE: %5.3f' % mse_p)
    plt.text(min(Y_pred)+0.05*rangex, max(Y_valid)-0.2*rangey, 'SEP: %5.3f' % sep)
    plt.text(min(Y_pred)+0.05*rangex, max(Y_valid)-0.25*rangey, 'RPD: %5.3f' % rpd)
    plt.text(min(Y_pred)+0.05*rangex, max(Y_valid)-0.3*rangey, 'Bias: %5.3f' %  bias)
    plt.show()    

prediction(X2_calib, Y_calib, X2_valid, Y_valid, plot_components=True)
```

And getting the error as:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 prediction(X2_calib, Y_calib, X2_valid, Y_valid, plot_components=True)
>   TypeError: prediction() takes at least 5 arguments (5 given)

Comment: This code snip is part of a class... Can you show more... And explain more about the problem!

Comment: Wow, what a terrible error message. But indeed, remove `self` from the function definition, or if it is really a method of a class, call it from an object of that class.